# how to insert line in file

Tags: python, string, writefile

I want to insert a line in a file. like below, insert '111' once 'AAA' appears

original file

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
AAA
```

and I want the result to be :

```
AAA
111
BBB
CCC
AAA
111
DDD
AAA
111
```

Here are my codes

```
with open(outfile, 'r+') as outfile:
        for line in outfile:    

            if line.startswith('AAA'):
                outfile.write('111\n')
                outfile.flush()
```

But it turns out that every time I run it, python just add '111' at the end of file, not just behind where 'AAA' starts, like below.

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
AAA111
```

There are some questions about this, but they are not properly answered. I really wonder the downvoters, do you have any problems ? or you cannot understand? or just because of some small mistakes that doesn't affect the question?

Comment: you have a missing `"` in your code

Comment: Why do you check, if the line starts with 'B'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Update the file inplace use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module,

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(outfile, inplace=True):
    if line.strip() == 'AAA':
        print line,
        print 111
    else:
        print line,
```

output:-

```
AAA
111
BBB
CCC
AAA
111
DDD
AAA
111
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but every time I use print, it will create a new line, which I don't want. How can I fix it?

Comment: Use, `print line.strip()` as line carries '\n' in itself(reading from file).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, and I also find a way to avoid newline, it's print XXXX, plus a ',' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`r+` addds to the end of the file. This is not what you want.
Just split your code into reading and writing:

```
filepath = "/file.txt"
with open(filepath, 'r') as infile:
    content = infile.readlines()

out = []
with open(filepath 'w') as outfile:
        for line in content:
            out.append(line)
            if line.startswith('A'):
                out.append("111\n")
        outfile.write("".join(out))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.rstrip() == "AAA":
            lines[ind] = line.rstrip() + "\n111\n"
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1:
        f1.writelines(lines)
```

Output:

```
AAA
111
BBB
CCC
AAA
111
DDD
AAA
111
```

If you want to write to a new file and avoid reading all the file into memory:

```
with open("in.txt") as f,open("output.txt","w") as f1:
    for  line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == "AAA":
            f1.write(line.rstrip() + "\n111\n")
        else:
            f1.write(line)
```